# table-cell height, img display: block

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My understanding of table-cell is that each table-cell's height will expand to be the same height as the tallest table-cell; however, in this example, `.col2`'s height extends below `.col1` when the `img` within `.col1` is set to `display: block` and the text within `.col2` is pushed all the way to the bottom. If `display: block` is removed from the `img`, `.col1` and `.col2` line up with the text aligned to the middle. My question is why does the `display: block` on the `img` change how the table-cells are rendered and how the text is aligned. Toggle `display: block` on the `img` to see the difference.

https://codepen.io/norkuy/pen/EvQQrE

## HTML

```
<div class="row1">
   <div class="col1">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/800/" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col2">
  <p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Amet 
 mollitia est maiores temporibus ea, sint ex repellat ipsa eveniet nesciunt.
</div></p>
 </div>
</div>

<p><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab veniam 
praesentium delectus aliquid ea nisi porro eius rem debitis architecto quas, 
hic placeat ratione possimus voluptates perferendis at voluptatibus tenetur!
</div></p>
```

## CSS

```
.col1, .col2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.col2 {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.row1 {
  display: table;
  img {
    display: block;
  }
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Paragraphs can't contain divs.

Comment: Try to use vertical-align: top; on your table-cell elements.

Comment: what you are missing is that your row should have `table-row` display

Comment: Removed divs within p tags for my Codepen example. Issue is still occuring. I'm not only looking for a solution, but also a "why" for why this is occuring.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think parts of the table that are missing are added as anonymous elements per the spec.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `table-cell` elements work properly, your cells container has to have `table-row` display

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
    <br/><br/>fdfsf
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
    dffdsf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove vertical-align: middle, the problem still occurs. It also occurs whether their is a display: table-row or not.